# Why during template deduction the right function is not seletected

Tags: c++, templates

I have defined two overloading template functions. Both of them take a function pointer as agument. The difference is that in the first  one, the function is a member of a class, but in the second  it is not.
When I try to pass in the template function, a non member function class, compiler does select the template function in which the function is a class member.
As a result compiler error is generated.

Below is the code

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>
#include <deque>
#include <thread>
#include <functional>

class Worker
{
public:
    Worker()
    {


    }
template<typename _Callable, typename Object, typename... _Args>
    void QueueFunction(_Callable __f, Object   obj, _Args... __args)
    {
           funcs.emplace_back([=]()mutable
                    {
                         (obj.*__f)(__args...);
                    });
           std::cout << "size::" <<funcs.size()<<std::endl;
           std::cout << funcs.empty()<<std::endl;
    }
    template<typename _Callable, typename... _Args>
    void QueueFunction(_Callable __f, _Args... __args)
    {

               funcs.emplace_back([=]()mutable
                        {
                             (*__f)(__args...);
                        });
    }
    std::deque<std::function<void()>> funcs;

};
void sub(int x ,int y)
{
               std::cout << "sub::result: " << x-y << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    Worker w;
    w.QueueFunction(&sub,5,6);
}
```

I expected that the following function wil be chosen

```
template<typename _Callable, typename... _Args>
void QueueFunction(_Callable __f, _Args... __args)
```

Comment: FYI, all identifiers containing double-underscores are reserved for the compiler, as well as all identifiers starting with an underscore followed by an upper-case letter. You really should not be using these naming conventions unless you are writing a compiler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SFINAE does not look at the function's body, only its declaration is taken into account.

What this implies is that when we are talking about overload resolution, your class looks like this:

```
class Worker
{
  template<typename A, typename B, typename... Cs>
  void QueueFunction(A a, B b, Cs... cs)
  {}

  template<typename A, typename Bs>
  void QueueFunction(A a, Bs... bs)
  {}
};
```

Taking that into account, it makes perfect sense that `w.QueueFunction(&sub,5,6);` binds more strongly to the first one.

**Edit:** What you are doing is basically reinventing `std::bind`, so you might as well use it instead. It will handle functors, member functions, and everything else smoothly all at once.

```
template<typename... Args>
void QueueFunction(Args&&... args) {
    funcs.emplace_back(std::bind(std::forward<Args>(args)...));
}
```

Comment: Great approach I will try this